# Error Installing Websense Software on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: java, windows, websense

I am trying to upgrade my current websense proxy manager (windows 2012 R2), and continuously get the below JDK error, approx 1 minute into install, then it crashes out.

Its an in place upgrade, so next step might be to wipe and build a new server, but id really rather avoid that if possible, as its a significant piece of work.

I've been researching online, and it seems to be a graphics related issue, but can't see why it causing an app install to crash :(

Would anyone have recommendations? I'm wondering is there a JAVA or GPU service i can disable while running upgrade?

Openjdk platform binary has stopped working.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:                        BEX64
  Application Name:                          javaw.exe
  Application Version:                       8.0.1520.16
  Application Timestamp:                     5a29ef24
  Fault Module Name:                         MSVCR80.dll
  Fault Module Version:                      8.0.50727.8428
  Fault Module Timestamp:                    520b0ac2
  Exception Offset:                          000000000001d4d4
  Exception Code:                            c000000d
  Exception Data:                            0000000000000000
  OS Version:                                6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:                                 6153
  Additional Information 1:                  588f
  Additional Information 2:                  588f2731257bb39c514cfe32b2a220be
  Additional Information 3:                  d3ad
  Additional Information 4:                  d3adc5abebf62b1e9b56224c436950af
```

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt server and install worked successfully. Still non the wiser on root cause though.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing javaw.exe with java.exe worked at other instance.